# A work is under CC-by-ND but author permits fan fictions

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

A person posts an e-book on some web site and attributes it as CC-by-ND. Then he creates a public discussion in Vkontakte with the subject ”Post fanfics of %e-book's name% here“. Nevertheless, is it legal to post fan fictions in that discussion (without asking the author first)? To post anywhere outside of that discussion?

Comment: It appears this question can be reduced to the age-old question of ["Is fan-fiction a derivative work?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_with_fan_fiction)

Comment: Depending on context, the author's invitation to post fanfics can be either interpreted as an open invitation to create and publish fan-fiction (in which case it might be hard to still claim a copyright violation when people do so) or as an invitation to help them find existing fanfiction on the web so the author can sue them. You might want to ask the author about their general stance on fanfiction based on their work.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably legal to post them there, it's probably not legal to post them anywhere else.

A copyright owner is free to grant multiple licences over their work (except that they can only grant 1 *exclusive* licence). In this case he has granted a general CC-by-ND licence to everyone. He has also granted a licence for derivative fan-fic but only if it is posted where he says.

At least, anyone sued for copyright breach would have a very strong defence along those lines.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the "one exclusive license" restriction. The definition I'm aware of is that an exclusive license is any license whose terms are not offered to anyone else. A common example where multiple exclusive licenses co-exist are geographically limited distribution rights with non-overlapping regions.

Comment: @MSalters no, an exclusive licence is where the holder has exclusive rights to the IP - that is they, and only they, are entitled to use it.